# Using the sum and index match array function to fill a table

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a Sum, If Error, Index and Match array formula but I keep getting zeros.

Below is the formula..
Index - D8:DF1213 is the actual data including the headings.

Match - A3 & A1 is "Price" & "Profit Center" I would like to extract

B8:B1213 & C8:C1213 is the columns where I can find Price & Profit Center

B2 is the date I need.

What can I do to make this work??

```
=+SUM(IFERROR(INDEX('Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$D$8:$DF$1213,+MATCH($A3&A$1,'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$B$8:$B$1213&'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$C$8:$C$1213,0),B2),0))
```

Below is a picture of the data I have set up. The columns are Dates and rows are the type of data I'd like to see whether its cost, material, overhead etc..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap9TU.jpg

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  If anything but a subscription to Office 365, did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?  Also a note: the two `+` are not needed.

Comment: Personally I would flip it a little and use SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS(INDEX('Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$D$8:$DF$1213,0,B2),'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$B$8:$B$1213,$A3,'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$C$8:$C$1213,A$1)`

Comment: Wait, B2 is a date.  Then you will need a MATCH in its place to find the correct column.  INDEX is expecting a relative column number and not the header value to find the column.

Comment: umm version 202, use I used ctrl-shift enter to make it an array function and I still got zero @ScottCraner

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to look at a relative column that does not exist and it is causing an error.  You need to add a MATCH function for the column: `MATCH(B2,'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$D$7:$DF$7,0)` or something similar and you will still need to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Right now it is trying to find column 42000 give or take a thousand depending on the date in B2.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just added a photo and more detail to show how my data is set up

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still having some trouble understand what you mean? So I need to have 2 separate matches in the formula? @ScottCraner

Comment: Yes.  One for the correct row and the other for the correct column.  INDEX by itself does not do a lookup.  It simply returns the value at the intersction of given relative row and column numbers.  By providing the date instead of the relative column in which that date is found, you are trying to return a column that does not exist.  This will return an error and the IFERROR is causing `0` to be returned.  Replace the `B2` in my formula with the MATCH I gave you and try that.

Comment: @ScottCraner I get "#VALUE" error  SUM(IFERROR(INDEX('Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$D$8:$DF$1213,+MATCH($A3&A$1,'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$B$8:$B$1213&'Develpoment 3Q EAC'!$C$8:$C$1213,0),match(B2,'Development 3Q EAC'!$AG$8:$AG$1213),0))

Comment: This still doesn't work, @ScottCraner